# Session: Configured driver 'files' was not found. Aborting

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

Being beginner in CodeIgniter, was trying to make login application. After doing some session's work,it's unable to load the login page which was getting loaded earlier.

Error is:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: UnexpectedValueException
>
> Message: Session: Configured driver 'files' was not found. Aborting.
>
> Filename:
>   C:\wamp64\www\CodeIgniter-3.0.1\system\libraries\Session\Session.php

Comment: show your config.php file's `Session Variables` section first

Comment: @RejoanulAlam                                                                                             $config['encryption_key'] = '';
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

Comment: have you loaded `session` library & `session` driver? in autoload.php?

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation','session');
$autoload['drivers'] = array('files');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is wrong in your autoload.php

```
$autoload['drivers'] = array('files');
```

change this as

```
$autoload['drivers'] = array('session');
```

and now check

Comment: Done but still got problems. I mean the same problem statement which i mentioned in question

Comment: If I don't add 'files' in drivers then problems that i mentioned in the question appears but if i add both session and files drivers in autoload then  it shows "Unable to load the requested class: Files"

Comment: There is nothing in Codeigniter named `Files`. Where you get this name to add in `drivers`?

Comment: It's an files driver for storing session data.http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session#session-drivers

Comment: There is no such thing as 'drives' autoload in CI.

Comment: $config['sess_driver']   = 'cookie'; comment this line in config/config.php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CI documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver).
If you are using files driver, you need to set a writable directory as the 'sess_save_path' configuration item. Yours is set to NULL.

> Another important thing that you should know, is to make sure that you don’t use a publicly-readable or shared directory for storing your session files. Make sure that only you have access to see the contents of your chosen sess_save_path directory. Otherwise, anybody who can do that, can also steal any of the current sessions (also known as “session fixation” attack).