# CodeIgniter Error : Message: Session: Configured driver 'files' was not found. Aborting

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

> Type: UnexpectedValueException
>
> Message: Session: Configured driver 'files' was not found. Aborting.
>
> Filename: /var/www/html/m-ticket/system/libraries/Session/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 230
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /var/www/html/m-ticket/application/controllers/Home.php
> Line: 8
> Function: __construct
>
> File: /var/www/html/m-ticket/index.php
> Line: 292
> Function: require_once

I copied this project from Windows and I would like to put it in Linux' localhost/m-ticket (/var/www/html/m-ticket) and I changed base_url localhost/m-ticket but I still got the error.

I read this
[Session: Configured driver 'files' was not found. Aborting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963734/session-configured-driver-files-was-not-found-aborting)

but it doesn't solve my problem

this is my autoload.php

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$autoload['packages'] = array();
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
$autoload['drivers'] = array('files');
$autoload['helper'] = array('file');
$autoload['config'] = array();
$autoload['language'] = array();
$autoload['model'] = array();
```

and also there's a helper in one of controllers

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'file', 'html', 'text', 'tgl', 'date'));
```

if I delete **files** from drivers autoload, it back to the **Type: UnexpectedValueException**

Comment: It's clearly saying you that `files` was not found , as it is a helper not a driver , show us your autoload file

Comment: **Thank you** .. it does solve my problem but I still get this error

Unable to load the requested file: helpers/files_helper.php

Comment: it should be a `file`  not `files` ,,, always do check the user guide for codeigniter : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Comment: it doesnt give me the file which have encountered the error, where do i have to change it?

Comment: inside auto load , replace : `files` with `file` in helper , let me post it as answer , with details

Comment: if I bring the **files** to **file**, it gets the same error like before

$autoload['helper'] = array('files');

Comment: If you are copying the files give the full permission to the copied files in your linux system.

Comment: should it 777? cause I give it 755

Comment: @MochamadLuckyPradana post code as well

Comment: @MochamadLuckyPradana check my answer , i told you to remove `files` from drivers , else you will continue getting the errors. do it.

Comment: @MochamadLuckyPradana  there is also problem with your Home.php controller's __construct , post that code as well

Answer (score 0):

First of all `files` is not a valid driver , what  you are looking for is a `file` helper which contains functions that assist in working with files. , so what you have to do is open `autoload.php` and

**remove the `files` from**

```
$autoload['drivers'] = array('files'); // remove files from this array
```

and add `file` inside helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('file');
```

as `file` is a helper not a driver , drivers can be `cache` , `session` ,`database`

and also seems like you have problems with saving the sessions , so this the following steps as well :

go to :

```
application/config/
```

and open

```
config.php
```

find `$config['sess_save_path']` and replace it with :

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

Comment: $autoload['drivers'] = array('files');
$autoload['helper'] = array('file');

it'll be like this right? I changed it and get this error


Unable to load the requested class: Files

Comment: @MochamadLuckyPradana  are you saving the autoload file ? , as error is saying `files` , but it is `file` , please double check

Comment: Please post your whole autoload.php file in question , i need to check it

Comment: @MochamadLuckyPradana   , i saw your autoload.php file , i told you to remove : `files` from drivers , do it.

Comment: Done.. but I get this error back 

Type: UnexpectedValueException

Message: Session: Configured driver 'files' was not found. Aborting.

Filename: /var/www/html/m-ticket/system/libraries/Session/Session.php

Line Number: 230

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/m-ticket/application/controllers/Home.php Line: 8 Function: __construct

File: /var/www/html/m-ticket/index.php Line: 292 Function: require_once

Comment: show me the __construct function of your file Home.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115487/discussion-between-mochamad-lucky-pradana-and-arsh-singh).

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I have checked my `"/public_html/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php"` and can see that `<b>Session_files_driver.php</b>` file is blank. I have copied the code from another same file. and put it into `<b>Session_files_driver.php</b>` and it's solved.